# Java ignore pagination when printing

Tags: java, swing, printing, clojure

I'm printing text in a dot matrix printer and i'm using swing's ([JTextArea](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html)) and its print method. The method prints a whole a4 page which is overkill and none of the predefined page sizes work for me. I'd like to be able to print only what i send to the printer and stop right there so it doesn't waste whitespace trying to fill an a4 page.

Sending the text to "lpt1" works but the font which the printer uses to print is useless (I need to be able to set the font).

The code if needed is this. It takes a string (s), creates a JTextArea (ta) with the string then uses the print method on it.

```
(defn print-string
  "Uses JtextArea."
  [s]
  (let [ta (JTextArea. s)]
    (.setFont ta (create-font (get-current-font) (get-current-font-size)))
    (try
      (.print ta nil nil false nil nil false)
      (catch Exception _
        (.print ta)))))
```

Edit: I'm adding a java version:

```
public static void print_string(String s) {
  JTextArea ta = new JTextArea(s);
  ta.setFont(create_font(get_current_font(), get_current_font_size()));
  try {
    ta.print(null, null, false, null, null, false);
  } catch (Exception e) {
    ta.print();
  }
}
```

Comment: "it's clojure code but it should be readable to "pure" java programmers" I'd tag it [clojure] as I personally do not understand it, and I am a "pure" java programer.

Comment: How will the page come out of the printer if you don't "fill" it with white space?

Comment: The page is actually a paper strip which can be cut at the desired length. Like a receipt printer. I only need to give the text about 10 newlines to have enough space to cut.